# IIS SMTP and .NET Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, smtp

The IIS SMTP setup seems to be quite a mess and a common question.  I've looked around and don't seem to find someone with this question though so hopefully together we can figure something out.

I'm trying to setup a WCF service that will fire off a email with some details from a database in it.  Sounds pretty simple right...?  All the references online I see have the SMTP configuration setup in the web.config file like:

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="mailer@dla.mil">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" userName="mygmailaccount" password="mypassword" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Problem is I can't have any passwords in plain text and my web server requires authentication.  So I found in IIS Manager you can setup the credentials in there like:

[image: iis image]

However, I can't figure out how to get the service to pickup these settings.  Am I missing something here?  Is this even possible?  If not, anyone got any ideas on a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the IIS SMTP service has nothing to do with the .NET `<smtp>` mail settings. It's just a server and doesn't interact with .NET unless you configure your application to send mail via the service. So just ignore it.

If you want your application to send email via GMail's SMTP servers you need to configure an application specific password for your web application.

You can find out how to do this here:

> [Sign in using application-specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

Basically you create a password specifically for your application. You can configure multiple passwords for different applications for use with the same GMail account. The idea being that if one or more of your applications are compromised then you can easily revoke the compromised application without having to reset passwords across multiple apps.

You type in the name of the application (say "My Web App") then click the "Generate Password" button. This will generate a random password that is specific to your application. Copy and paste the password into the `password` attribute of your `smtp/network` configuration element then get your application to send an email.

With regards to not being able to store your Gmail passwords in plain-text you could use the Protected Configuration feature which is documented here:

> [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx)

There are some sections that can't be encrypted and if the `smtp/network` setting is one of these then just move the password to an `<appSettings>` key/value pair and encrypt that section. It just means that your app would need to go the extra step to read the password and set that when using the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`.

Comment: Thanks!  Found a great article here: http://forums.asp.net/p/953254/1166980.aspx#1166980

Comment: @amcdnl - glad I was able to point you in the right direction :)